Why does `using namespace` interfere with default arguments?
In a minimal project with three files, I have
main.cpp
#include "my_class.h"

using namespace foo::bar::baz;

int main()
{
    printDefault();
}

my_class.h:
namespace foo::bar
{
namespace baz
{
    void doDefault(bool actually = false);
    void printDefault();
}
}

and my_class.cpp
#include "my_class.h"

#include <stdio.h>

// using namespace foo::bar;
namespace foo::bar
{
namespace baz
{
void doDefault(bool actually /* = false*/)
{
    actually ? printf("true") : printf("false");
}

void printDefault()
{
    doDefault();
}
} // namespace baz
} // namespace foo::bar

This works fine.
However, if I change my_class.cpp like this:
#include "my_class.h"

#include <stdio.h>

using namespace foo::bar;

namespace baz
{
void doDefault(bool actually /* = false*/)
{
    actually ? printf("true") : printf("false");
}

void printDefault()
{
    doDefault();
}
} // namespace baz

it doesn't compile anymore, because the argument bool actually has no default value anymore. I'd have to call it with an explicit argument. (Calling it with an argument doesn't work either. I mixed something up here before creating the minimal example).

error C2660: 'baz::doDefault': function does not take 0 arguments

Why is that?

Please directly add the version that doesn't compile. Describing the code only in text isn't ideal.

Besides showing us a [mre] of the code that doesn't build, also copy-paste (as text) the full and complete build-log from it.

I tested, it works here: https://godbolt.org/z/7h59PKax6

Because the full namespace of your functions is foo::bar::baz, the definitions won't match the declarations if you replace namespace foo::bar {} with just using namespace foo::bar, since that would put your function definitions in a completely separate namespace called baz.

@AykhanHagverdili You tested the working example :p

@Violet OP hadn't added the non-working example when I tested it and it wasn't clear what the issue was

using namespace whatever; means that name lookup will look in namespace whatever, but it doesn't mean that any definitions you write automatically define things in namespace whatever.
If you do
using namespace foo::bar;

namespace baz
{
void doDefault(bool actually /* = false*/)
{
    actually ? printf("true") : printf("false");
}

void printDefault()
{
    doDefault();
}
} // namespace baz

then you're defining baz::doDefault and baz::printDefault, not foo::bar::baz::doDefault and foo::bar::baz::printDefault. baz::doDefault doesn't have a default argument value, so trying to call it with 0 arguments is invalid.
